# Android dynamic feature access fragment from main app with proguard enabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I have one dynamic feature. And when i enable proguard and i try to access fragment

```
if (splitManager.installedModules.contains(name)) {
            val fragment = "com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.AAFragment"
            val fr = activity!!.classLoader.loadClass(fragment)
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayoutContainer, (fr as Class<Fragment>).newInstance())
                .commit()
        }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.AAFragment" on path: DexPathList
```

If i try with disable proguard it works.

I try to keep class fragment in dynamic feature but it does not work.

How can i reach dynamic feature fragment? Thanks

Comment: hi @android_developer, did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: `-keep` that fragment.